# comprehensive overview of techniques for finding the difference between vectors

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

There are many techniques for finding the difference between two vectors.

for example:

- the norm of the difference.
- absolute value of the difference
- Mahalanobis distance
- Bhattacharyya distance

etc ..

I'm looking for a paper or other document outlining a comprehensive overview of techniques for finding the difference between vectors/function/distribution. It's also OK if the paper covers generalizations of these equations in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it!

[The Encyclopedia of Distances](http://www.uco.es/users/ma1fegan/Comunes/asignaturas/vision/Encyclopedia-of-distances-2009.pdf)